# How Migration Works in Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unity-container, repository-pattern

> Currently I am developing Large N-tire Application in Asp.Net MVC and
>   want to Separate Data,Entity,Service,Repository(Generic repository
>   with Unit Of works) I have reference  [Long Le article](http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/) in Class
>   library project so I can reuse code in both controller and in Web API
>   Controller with code first entity framework and migration occurs if
>   model is changed.So,please suggest best approach for above
>   understanding?

**As I have created separate project is there any effect in future while doing migration ?**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need repository pattern with Entity Framework Code First, because DbContext implements repository pattern and unit of work.

I usually define common database interface. Something like that:

```
public interface IDatabase
{
    IDbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Then I implement interface with my DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDatabase
{
    public IDbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

You can create a context for testing purposes

```
public class MyMockContext : IDatabase
{
    public IDbSet<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

But in your controller you always dependency-inject IDatabase. So that it's not dependent on any concrete implementation (and I use EFMock library in my tests).

Comment: I don't think so, How Its possible? If I don't create repository pattern then I need to create instance of DbContext in Controller's action  method and this is not the repository pattern.

Comment: @anomepani I have updated my answer, let me know if you have questions.